# getUser() return 0 on the first page load

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When a user is connected with Facebook and came on my page getUser() return 0.

I use this code:

```
include 'includes/php/facebook.php';
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "SECRET_KEY";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true 
));    

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user){
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
```

When the page is loaded completely the FB.Event return "connected".

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         window.location.reload();
     });

});
```

And then the page loaded twice. After this the User is connected with my page.

Is that correct, the page must loaded twice ? I think this is not user friendly. Knows someone another possibility ?

Why getUser() return 0 on the first page load ?

EDIT 2:

When I use the example from the Server-Side Authentication. And the User ist connected with Facebook, i get the user-details.

```
 <?php 

 $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
 $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
 $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

 session_start();
 $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 if(empty($code)) {
   $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

 $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);

 $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
   . $params['access_token'];

 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 echo("Hello " . $user->name);
}
else {
  echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
}

?>
```

When the user is not connected with Facebook, I get the dialog before i came back to my page. Can i also query the connection to facebook without the dialog ? Or can i on an other way genereate the CSRF ?

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to authenticate the user using a server-side or client-side flow? (that is using php or js)

Comment: With a server-side, but getUser() return 0 and then i test it with the client-side (FB.Event) and this return "connected". I don't understand, why getUser() return 0 on the first page load ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just did not post the code with which you authenticate the user, or you just don't do that part..
It's not enough to construct a Facebook object, you need to authenticate the user with facebook.

Have you read the authentication documentation?
There are two types of flows you can take, the [Server-Side](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) and [Client-Side](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/), from your code it seems like you need to use the server side flow in order to have an access token for the user on the php side, then the call for the *getUser* method should return the user object you want.

If I'm mistaken and you are authenticating the user, then please edit your question and add the code you use for that.

Comment: I use the Server-Side and the User authenticating it. This is not the problem. But when a user came back to my page and it is connected with facebook, i will connected the user automatically on my page.

Comment: So I test the connection with the Client-Side. And when I use: FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) { console.log(response)}); it response on the first page load the user is "connected" with Facebook. How know the FB.Event this ? And why i can call up this with the php sdk on the first page load ?

Comment: Have you implemented the server-side auth flow correctly? Probably not since it does not work for you. Please, read the [Server-Side Authentication document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), there's a **full** php example there, have you used it? If so, please **edit your original** question with the code you are using, all of it that is relevant, it's impossible to help you like this.